# Apache - Multiple sites - One Server - Different Ports - Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Currently I have an Apache2 listening on Port 80.
This is configured in /etc/apache2/listen.conf

In /etc/apache2/conf.d I have the normal configuration files and:

**site1.conf**,
**site2.conf** and
**site3.conf**
files.

Each conf file is configured very similar :

```
Alias /site1 /home/user/www/site1/

AddHandler cgi-script cgi

<Directory "/home/user/www/site1/">
  AllowOverride All
  Options +ExecCGI

  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </IfModule>

  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
</Directory>
```

So going to my browser I can enter:

http://10.10.0.1/site1 and get site1, http://10.10.0.1/site2 and get site2 etc

This works fine internally.

I'd now like to allow site2 and site3 to be accessed externally.

If I open port 80 on my router and route it to 10.10.0.1 then all sites are available.

I've added 8080 & 8888 to /etc/listen.conf and edited site2.conf as :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 Alias /site2 /home/user/www/site2/

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi

    <Directory "/home/user/www/site2/">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI

      <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
      </IfModule>

      <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </IfModule>

      DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and site3 the same but setting the VirtualHost to *:8888

This works. I can access site2 only on 8080 and site3 only on 8888 **BUT**

I can also access site1 on port 8080 and port 8888

What I want is :

- site1 is only available from port 80
- site2 is only available from port 8080
- site3 is only available from port 8888

The router only has 8080 and 8888 open and routing.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I've never tried</s> I just tested using Apaches `DocumentRoot` directive without a corresponding `ServerName` named host - and I got it working on my machine.
The idea is to try and get the virtual host to match to a filepath, try replacing this:

```
Alias /site2 /home/user/www/site2/
```

with

```
DocumentRoot /home/user/www/site2
```

[Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) says

> The DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.

so you get

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 DocumentRoot /home/user/www/site2

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi

    <Directory "/home/user/www/site2/">
      AllowOverride All
      Options +ExecCGI

      <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
      </IfModule>

      <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </IfModule>

      DirectoryIndex index.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Try on one virtualhost website combination, if it works repeat on the others. - dont forget to restart apache after you modify the vhosts - you will probably have to if you change the `Listen` directive.

Apache has [a guide on running multiple website on different ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port).
This is based on apache 2.2  and docs say

> [you must use] NameVirtualHost x.x.x.x:8080 - without the NameVirtualHost name:port or you try to use the Listen directive, your configuration will not work.

I tested on 2.4 on Ubuntu without the `NameVirtualHost` and it worked fine for me

Comment: Thanks I will try this. One of my conf files has multiple aliases, each going to different locations locally. How would I add them ?

Comment: I would just try get the virtualhost matching to the file paths first, I had to make multiple attempts configuring apache to get it to work on my machine, including tracking, then responding to, apache's error logs. Then try adding your aliases  - and again track log output - if you cant sort it then post another question providing all details

Comment: Thanks _ I've got this working for one site using port 80 and another using port 8080. I have a slight issue with a 3rd site. But will raise that as a new question.

Comment: cool, glad you got it working!